# Need assistance regarding disappearing paste menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In my messaging app I have [HPGrowingTextView](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView) at the bottom and `UITableview` covering rest of the the view to show messages. When user tap on `HPGrowingTextView` I resize the `UITableview` and slide up the `HPGrowingTextView` so nothing hides behind keyboard.

But when user perform `long press gesture` on `HPGrowingTextView` everything works same but `paste menu` appears and then disappear.

How can I control the disappearing of `paste menu`.